# error custom select

Tags: html, css

He creado un formulario con distintas columnas y demás, me han aparecido varios fallos, y uno de ellos es en los `select`. En el anterior formulario que no existían las particiones de la página en forma de columnas, este estilo funcionaba perfecto. Como funcionaba bien, lo copié y pegué adaptándolo al nuevo formato, pero nada.

```css
/*CASILLA SELECCIONAR*/   
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #C81A1A;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected: after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected .select-arrow-active: after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C81A1A;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-3"> 
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100%;">
     <option value="0">Elige uno:</option>
     <option value="1">Uno</option>
     <option value="2">Dos</option>
     <option value="3">Tres</option> 
  </select><br>
</div>
```

El problema es que no me aparece el estilo, aparte, quiero subirlo más, al nivel de las checkboxes, pero no sé cómo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas usando bootstrap, sospecho que el problema que tienes es que no has puesto tus estilos en último lugar. Es decir, cuando haces las referencias a los diferentes ficheros, pon tu fichero el último. De esta manera, tus estilos serán los últimos en aplicarse y no habrá otras clases que los sobreescriban (si que puede que se sobreescriban por especificidad).

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Tenía ya el css en último lugar, ya me pasó con otra cosa y aprendí de ello.

Comment: Lo que parece faltarte es toda la parte de Javascript. Si te das cuenta los **CSS** hacen referencia a clases que no aparecen en el **HTML** y que seguramente se añaden desde Javascript. Buscando encontré el sitio de donde pareces haber sacado el código y si te fijas más abajo del **CSS** se encuentra el Javascript asociado: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: @phpMyGuel Anda, no me había fijado en esa parte! Entonces ese código de js se añade en el body del html, ¿no?

Comment: Yo suelo añadir mis etiquetas `<script>` justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre del `<body>` para que no existan problemas de hacer referencia a elementos que aun no han cargado en el **DOM**.

Comment: Ya está añadido y sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizás debas poner un poco más de información de que quieres hacer, es que en tu HTML no veo que ninguna de las opciones del select tengan una clase asignada, por ejemplo en tu CSShaces referencia a la clase `.select-items` supuestamente esta clase le aplica el estilo a los items del select pero ningún option tiene esta clase aplicada y como este caso no veo correspondencia entre tu HTML y el CSS.

Quizás debas revisar tu HTML, yo asigné la clase que antes te mencioné a los options y el estilo se aplicó correctamente al igual que otras clases, también quieres subir el select al nivel de los checkboxes pero que clase tienes aplicada a los checkboxes, recuerda que bootstrap tiene 12 columnas por fila, como puedes ver al select le estás aplicando que se corra 7 y que tenga de tamaño 3 lo que implica que suman 10, si los checkboxes están una caja con más de 2 columnas pues tu select bajará a una nueva fila y por eso no se posiciona al lado de los checkboxes.

Prueba algo así para alinear tu select con los checkboxes

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="checkbox">Check
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select>
      <option>Value 1</option>
      <option>Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funcionó lo de alinearlo, pero no entendí muy bien lo de las clases de los select. ¿Dices de añadir la clase "item" a cada option? ¿Y así funcionaría?

Comment: depende de lo que quieras realizar, es que como te contestaron anteriormente seguro tu javascript aplicaba los estilos en dependencia de la acción que quisieras realizar, ahora mismo lo que yo veo es tienes un select que no tiene ninguna clase asignada en el css por lo tanto ninguno de tus estilos se aplicaran a tu página porque ningún option tiene clase asignada por ejemplo yo haría esto <option class="select-items">Value 2</option> esto lo haría con los option a los que quiera aplicarle el estilo